# Extract variable references in Javac

Tags: java, compiler-construction, static-analysis

I am developing a java program extends TreeScanner from com.sun.source.util. I am looking for sth like visitMethodInvocation, but for variable.

I was wondering if there is a way to extract variable references when visitVariable is called? Or please let me know what is the best way to extract variable references using TreeScanner.

A simple example: In the below code when a method is visited (visitMethod), I extract all its statements and then call VariableTreeScanner. I was wondering if I can extract variable references in visitvariable?

```
public static class MethodTreeScanner extends TreeScanner<Void, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void visitMethod(MethodTree arg0, Void arg1) {
        List<? extends StatementTree> statements = arg0.getBody().getStatements();
        for(StatementTree statementTree: statements) {

            Kind statementKind = statementTree.getKind();
            if (statementKind.equals(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE)) {
                statementTree.accept(new VariableTreeScanner (compilationUnitTree, sourcePositions, arg0.getName().toString()), null);
        }
    }
}

public static class VariableTreeScanner extends TreeScanner<Void, Void> {
     @Override
     public Void visitVariable(VariableTree arg0, Void arg1) {
           // I like to extract variable references here, or let me know if there is a better way to do this.
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is a `visitIdentifier` (and variable references are `Identifier`) but no `visitVariableReference` or the likes. I'm not an expert on Java parsing, but I think it's possible that at the point that the TreeScanner operates, it's not possible yet to link Identifier to their declaration. E.g. there may be forward references that cannot be resolved to variable declarations yet. Also references with qualifiers such as `Foo.this.bar` are constructed from several identifiers. So my guess is that a seperate pass is required to construct variable references from Identifiers.

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to do conceptually?

Comment: What do you mean, "extract variable references"?  What do you mean by variable reference?  And why are you converting kinds to Strings in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. you are right, I removed toString. By variable reference I mean where a variable is used.

Comment: You want to build a cross reference of uses of all variables?  Or you want to find uses of a suddenly specified variable at some moment to accomplish some other task?

Comment: The First case: build a cross reference of uses of all variables

Comment: Do you just want the answer (I can point to one integrated into a Javadoc like form), or do you specifically want to build the tool?  What will you *do* with the answer?